# How to login to facebook and get user access token using httpwebrequest?

Tags: c#, facebook, httpwebrequest

I am trying to log in to facebook account with my email and password to get user access token by using httpwebrequest. 
I did not know how to use it because cookies is very complicated to me. Does anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

you can find a simple example on here

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/380635/Csharp-Application-Integration-with-Facebook-Twitt

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ASP.NET MVC WebHelper package from nuGet, it provides out of the box integration possibilities to integrate your website with facebook, twitter and so on.